# Pythonic way of converting a list embedded in a string to a list

Tags: python

I am not sure if there is a solution for this on stack overflow; so apologies if this is a duplicate.

There are number of ways of converting the string:

```
s = '[1, 2, 3]'
```

to a list

```
t = [1, 2, 3]
```

but I am looking for the most straightforward pythonic way of doing this. Also, performance matters.

Comment: Yes I did. But given the performance, would eval be fine? I am simply dealing with integer lists here.

Comment: I don't understand why some would down rank this. I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should use [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('[1,2,3]')
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: you mean `import ast`

Comment: Yeah, I did just that. Thanks.

Comment: instead of importing ast , Just do eval('[1,2,3]')

Comment: @NileshG `eval` is unsafe and should not be used. `ast.literal_eval` is *much* safer

Answer (score 1):

Why never use json library.

```
import json
# convert str to list 
t = json.loads(s)

# back to string
s2 = json.dumps(t)
```

Comment: For a list of integers, this is a reasonable approach.